Distribution of binned Poissonian variable
I'm investigating a crude model of shot noise in camera pixels.  Mathematically, I'm interested in the distribution of a random variable $\lfloor n/C\rfloor$, where $n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $C \gg 1$ is a fixed real number.  The question is, what is the distribution of $\lfloor n/C\rfloor$?
The idea behind this model is that the number of photons $n$ incident on a camera pixel is Poissonian, but it takes $C$ photons to increment the grayscale value of the image.  I asked essentially this same question first on stats.SE, but this may be a more appropriate SE for this question.

Denote $Y=\lfloor n/C\rfloor$. $Y$ can take any value in $\mathbb N$. For $k\in\mathbb N$, lets compute $\mathbb P(Y=k)$:
$$Y=k\iff k\leqslant n/C<k+1\iff kC\leqslant n< (k+1)C\iff \lceil kC \rceil\leqslant n <(k+1)C$$
For the upper bound on $n$, it really depends on wether $(k+1)C\in\mathbb N$ or not. If it does, then
$$Y=k\iff \lceil kC\rceil \leqslant n \leqslant \lfloor (k+1)C \rfloor -1$$
otherwise,
$$Y=k\iff \lceil kC\rceil \leqslant n \leqslant \lfloor (k+1)C \rfloor $$
In every case, denote $M_k$ this upper bound. Then, for all $k\in\mathbb N$, you can compute
$$\mathbb P(Y=k)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{j=\lceil kC\rceil}^{M_k} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!}$$
If you have additional knowledge on $\lambda$ and $C$, I guess you could numerically compute about everything you would need to know. Hope it helps in some way.
